# post request is not working properly, Some data are going but some are not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

**Request:**

```
{
    "title": "Wake up and smell the coffee",
    "message": "In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Wikipedia",
    "creator": "Shravan",
    "tags": [
        "tag1",
        "tag2"
    ],
    "selectedFile": "www.selectedfile.jpg"
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "tags": [],
    "likeCount": 0,
    "createdAt": "2020-12-21T19:12:05.908Z",
    "_id": "5fe0f38c8e9dcb0eb07a9a56",
    "__v": 0
}
```

**Model/Schema:**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  message: String,
  creator: String,
  tags: [String],
  selectedFile: String,
  likeCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date(),
  },
});

var PostMessage = mongoose.model("PostMessage", postSchema);

export default PostMessage;
```

**Server.js:**

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";

import PostMessage from "./models/postMessage.js";
// routes
// import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";

const app = express();

app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.query;
  PostMessage.create(data, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  });
});

// limit: "30mb",
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

// app.use(express.json());

const CONNECTION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.9ey4m.mongodb.net/dbTest?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

// mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
```

can anyone help me?

**Because I am not getting any right answer, I have been trying to find the answer for the last 5 days continuously.**

Comment: what is the error? could you share the expected and actual result?

Answer (score 0):

1. Middlewares should be above the route, in order to pre-process the request object.
2. `req.query` should be `req.body` if it's a post request.

`req.body` is where the middleware stores the data extracted from the Request object, [per docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json):

> (...) parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body), or an empty object ({}) if there was no body to parse, the Content-Type was not matched, or an error occurred.

The code should be:

```
//bodyparser package not needed anymore.

// 1. middlewares
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors()); //you can remove this an set header manually

// 2. routes
app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  PostMessage.create(data, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  });
});
```